There is a N+1 issue, after migration spring boot 2.7.2 -> 3.2.2. Using @BatchSize, but just in Codition size decreasing
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void test() {
    Slice<Team> teamSlice = teamRepository.findAllLimit10();
    List<Team> teamList = teamSlice.getContent();
    List<Boolean> booleanList = teamList.stream()
                                        .map(team -> {
                                            team.getUserList().isEmpty(); // issue point
                                        })
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

}

@Builder.Default
@Where(clause = "enabled = true")
@BatchSize(size = 600)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.userId,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    )
Hibernate:
select
    u1_0.user_id,
    u1_0.team_id
from
    user u1_0
where
    u1_0.team_id in(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
  and (
    u1_0.enabled = 1
    ) 

After spring boot migration, the issue arose.
spring boot 2.7.2 0> 3.2.2 and using hibernate-core 6.1.4 final.
Condition number is only decreasing...
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) <- It's effective. It's not a fundamental solution
fetch join <- org.hibernate.orm.query : HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory

I changed hibernate version 6.1.4.final -> 6.2.29.final.
Then the problem has been solved...
